# Items in grid are not updating after I update the useState in react native applcation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a react native project. Part of my react native project is a grid that I created. When a user clicks on an item in the grid, I want to update an array that I have set in state `const [selectedHomeTypes, setSelectedHomeTypes] = useState(['Houses'])`.

When I add an item to the array, I want it to udpate the grid so that all the items in the array have a blue background. If there was 1 item in `selectedHomeTypes` then 1 item in the grid has a blue background. If I add a second item to `selectedHomeTypes`, I want two items in the grid to have a blue background and sale with when I unselect an item that is deleted from the array.

What is hapening now is that `selectedHomeTypes` is being updated like normal so when an item that is not in the state is clicked on it is added to the array and same with unslelect. The issue is that the background colors of the items are not updating at all and no matter what happens, only the default item has blue background. Nothing is visually changing....

Main Screen:

```
const [selectedHomeTypes, setSelectedHomeTypes] = useState(['Houses'])
const updateSelectedHomeTypes = (selected) => {
  let selectedHome = selectedHomeTypes
  if(selectedHome.length == 0){
    setSelectedHomeTypes(['Houses'])
  }
  if(selectedHome.includes(selected)){
    let target = selectedHome.indexOf(selected)
    selectedHome.splice(target, 1)
    if(selectedHome.length == 0){
      setSelectedHomeTypes(['Houses'])
    } else {
      setSelectedHomeTypes(selectedHome)
    }
  } else {
    selectedHome.push(selected)
    setSelectedHomeTypes(selectedHome)
  }
}

  return (
    <View style={styles.filterContainer}>
      <ScrollView style={styles.scrollContainer}>
        <View style={styles.header}>
          <Text style={styles.label}>
            Filter
          </Text>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {resetFilter()}}>
            <Text style={[styles.label, styles.blueText]}>
              Reset
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
          <FlatList 
            style={styles.homeTypeContainer}
            data={homeTypeOptions1}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.key}
            numColumns={numberOfColumns}
            renderItem={(item) => {
              return(               
                <GridItemComponent 
                  item={item} 
                  updateSelectedHomeTypes={updateSelectedHomeTypes}
                  selectedHomeTypes={selectedHomeTypes}
                />
              )}}
          />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {applyFilters()}}>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Apply Filters</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
```

gridItemComponenet:

```
const GridItemComponent = (props) => {
  const {
    item,
    updateSelectedHomeTypes,
    selectedHomeTypes
  } = props

  return(
    <>
      {
        selectedHomeTypes.includes(item.item.value) ? <TouchableOpacity  style={styles.itemContainerBlue} onPress={() => {updateSelectedHomeTypes(item.item.value)}}>
                                                        <View style={styles.item}>
                                                          <Image style={styles.icon} source={item.item.image}/>
                                                          <Text style={styles.label}>{item.item.value}</Text>
                                                        </View>
                                                      </TouchableOpacity>
                                                    : <TouchableOpacity  style={styles.itemContainer} onPress={() => {updateSelectedHomeTypes(item.item.value)}}>
                                                        <View style={styles.item}>
                                                          <Image style={styles.icon} source={item.item.image}/>
                                                          <Text style={styles.label}>{item.item.value}</Text>
                                                        </View>
                                                      </TouchableOpacity>
          }
    </>
  )
}
```

list of property type options:

```
const numberOfColumns = 3

const homeTypeOptions1 = [
  {
    key: 1,
    value: 'Houses',
    image: require('./src/assets/home.png')
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    value: 'Condos',
    image: require('./src/assets/building.png')
  },
  {
    key: 3,
    value: 'Lot/Land',
    image: require('./src/assets/management.png')
  },
  {
    key: 4,
    value: 'Multi-family',
    image: require('./src/assets/multi-family.png')
  },
  {
    key: 5,
    value: 'Manufactured',
    image: require('.//src/assets/tiny-house.png')
  },
  {
    key: 6,
    value: 'Townhomes',
    image: require('.//src/assets/townhouse.png')
  }
]
```

as you can see in the image below, the `selectedHomeTypes` has 3 items in the array but only 1 item is highlighted. I am having trouble trying to update the background color of selected items dynamically

[image: 3 items selected but 1 item with blue background]

-----------UPDATE---------------------

how would I updated an array in `useState` if I want to eliminate an item from the array and have it rerender once the item was eliminated from the array. Keep in mind I have the index of the iteam I want to eliminate.

```
  const updateSelectedHomeTypes = (selected) => {
    let selectedHome = selectedHomeTypes
    if(selectedHome.length == 0){
      setSelectedHomeTypes(['Houses'])
    }
    if(selectedHome.includes(selected)){
      let target = selectedHome.indexOf(selected)
      selectedHome.splice(target, 1)
      setSelectedHomeTypes(selectedHome)
    } else {
      setSelectedHomeTypes([...selectedHome, selected])
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is `selected` a state property ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a glance I think this is the problem:

When you do this:

```js
selectedHome.push(selected)
setSelectedHomeTypes(selectedHome)
```

React doesn't re-render because you're setting `selectedHomeTypes` to the same array that's already in state.

You've pushed a new entry into it but React is doing an *identity* comparison between the old state and the new state to decide whether a rerender is needed. In this case `newArray === oldArray` so it doesn't trigger an update.

You could dodge this by spreading into a new array (and appending the new item instead of calling push):

```js
setSelectedHomeTypes([...selectedHome, selected])
```

Comment: does that also work the same way If i want to get rid of an object from an array that is used as a useState if I know the index of the array item I want to get rid of. I will add an updated to the original question to show my code for that.

Comment: As long as it's the same array you'll see this behavior. So if you use splice to remove the elements you'll have the same problem. And again, you could solve it via spread,  which creates a new array: `setSelectedHomeTypes([...selectedHome])`.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that state is meant to be immutable (React docs for it: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate), otherwise we run into bugs like this one or worse. Here's another answer discussing more about it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40309023/12026911

Answer (score 0):

When updating state using its previous value, use the callback argument (to avoid stale state values).

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

It should be

```
this.setState(state=>
    ({selectedHomeTypes: state.selectedHomeTypes.concat(selected)})
);
```

If you are updating a state property, using another state property, it's best to use class components.

State updates to arrays should be done using methods that return a new array (`push` does not while `concat` does).

See [this comprehensive article](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-state-array-add-update-remove/) to learn how to update state arrays in React.